# Connecting to localhost from another device on the same network using localhost not the server's IP address

Tags: android, push-notification, localhost

Long story short: I need to use push notifications for a project. The thing is I can't have push notifications on a website if I don't have https and since the project is only local that's a no-no. Google allows push notifications on localhost but not on the lan. So I want to directly connect to my apache2 server from my android device using localhost and not the servers IP (ex 192.168.1.70). I heard you can do that through proxies but I have no idea what should I do and google isn't helpful either..

Comment: You need to use the server IP... `localhost` always refers to the current device

Comment: And even if the project is "only local", you could still try Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: the problem is a web app, not an android app. And as I said if I'll use the servers IP address notifications won't work

Comment: I guess I am confused when you say "directly connect to my apache2 server from my android device using localhost" ,then